# Javascript looping through a json object

Tags: javascript

I know this has probably been asked a million times but I spent the whole day and I cannot resolve my problem. So here it is. I have a json object in the following format.

So I am trying to loop through this json object but just cannot be able to do. I simply can get iy working. For example:

```js
const json = [
  [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Jeffreys Bay",
    "ProvinceID": 1
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Heidelberg",
    "ProvinceID": 3
  }]
]

for (let x in json) {
  console.log(x + ': ' + json[x]);
}
```

returns

```
core.js:6479 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (location.page.ts:71)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

Please help me??

Comment: [There is no JSON anywhere in your question](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Your code does not throw the error you say it does

Comment: What you have is an array of arrays of objects.  And [your loop produces no error](https://jsfiddle.net/oktxeycn/).  Where is there any JSON being parsed?

Comment: The object is an array inside an array, either make it a simple array, or run two loops inside of each other.

Comment: You have double [ ] try to remove one. You got object of object there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```js
const json = [
  [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Jeffreys Bay",
    "ProvinceID": 1
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Heidelberg",
    "ProvinceID": 3
  }]
]

for (let x in json) {
  console.log(x + ': ' + JSON.stringify(json[x]));
}
```